# keras model.predict IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I trained a keras model with my own images, and I have defined an output layer of 3 neurons, but when I try to predict an individual image using model.predict(img) it returns a value out of range, so in my network it should only output the values 0, 1 and 2, but it is outputting values like 4, 6, etc.

Here follows the network code:

```
from textwrap import indent
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
import cv2 as cv
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models


def main(training_images, training_labels, test_images, test_labels, single_image=None):

    #learnModel(training_images, training_labels, test_images, test_labels)
    predictionModel(single_image)


def learnModel(training_images, training_labels, test_images, test_labels):
    #define the model, train it and save it
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(280, 400, 1))) 
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu')) #Convulotional layers filters images by their features (example: a cat has small legs)
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2))) #Max Pooling layers filter the important information
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')) #Last layer
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=10, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
    
    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
    print(f"Loss: {loss}")
    print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy}")
    
    model.save('retina_disease_classifier.model')


def predictionModel(single_image):
    model = models.load_model('retina_disease_classifier.model') #This loads an already trained model

    class_names = ['Healthy', 'Glaucomatous', 'Diabetic Retinopathy']

    img = cv.imread(single_image)

    img = np.array([img]).reshape(-1, 280, 400, 1) / 255
    prediction = model.predict(img)
    index = np.argmax(prediction)
    print(f"Prediction is {class_names[index]}")
```

Here is the code where I build the traning data, labels and test data:

```
from PIL import Image
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from matplotlib import image
from matplotlib.pyplot import show
from numpy import asarray, single
import numpy as np
import sys
import logging
import gzip
import convNetwork


imageDatasetPath = "./Dataset/"
singleImagePath = "./Dataset/34761_dr.jpg"

imageLength = 400
imageHeigth = 280
imagePixelNum  = imageLength * imageHeigth


def main():

    training_images = createTrainingImages(imageDatasetPath)
    training_labels = createTrainingLabels(imageDatasetPath)
    test_images= createTrainingImages(imageDatasetPath)
    test_labels = createTrainingLabels(imageDatasetPath)

    #convNetwork.main(training_images, training_labels, test_images, test_labels)
    convNetwork.main(training_images, training_labels, test_images, test_labels, single_image=singleImagePath)


def createTrainingImages(imageDatasetPath):
    files = [f for f in listdir(imageDatasetPath) if isfile(join(imageDatasetPath, f))]
    training_images = []

    for fileName in files:
        imagePath = imageDatasetPath + fileName
        training_images.append(convertImageArray(imagePath))
    
    training_images = np.array(training_images).reshape(-1, imageHeigth, imageLength, 1)

    return training_images


def createTrainingLabels(imageDatasetPath):
    files = [f for f in listdir(imageDatasetPath) if isfile(join(imageDatasetPath, f))]
    training_labels = []

    for fileName in files:
        imagePath = imageDatasetPath + fileName
        training_labels.append(getDiseaseType(fileName))

    training_labels = np.reshape(training_labels, (len(training_labels), 1))

    return training_labels


def convertImageArray(imagePath): 
    image = Image.open(imagePath)
    # convert image to numpy array
    data = asarray(image)
    #data = np.reshape(data, (imagePixelNum, 1))
    data = data / 255
    return data


def getDiseaseType(imageName):
    condition = imageName.split('.')[0]
    condition = condition.split('_')[1]

    if(condition == "h"):
        return 0
    elif(condition == "g"):
        return 1
    elif(condition == "dr"):
        return 2
    else:
        logging.error("Invalid Input")

main()
```

This is the error that I get:

```
File "./convNetwork.py", line 76, in predictionModel
    print(f"Prediction is {class_names[index]}")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

From what I understand the number of output neurons is defined in this way:
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
So, I dont understand how it is returning more outputs than the maximum defined.